# How to cache results when using reactive subscription?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, system.reactive

In a Blazor server-side app I have a component that is basically a dropdown list for postcodes. I use [Reactive](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) to make the calls to an endpoint that finds matching postcodes by search criteria.

I initialize the subscription as follows:

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();

    searchSubscription = searchSubject
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        .Select(async criteria => new
        {
            query = criteria,
            results = await service.FindPostCodesAsync(criteria)
        })
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(async search =>
        {
            if (search?.results != null)
            {
                postCodes = search.results
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Code).ThenBy(p => p.City).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                postCodes = new List<PostCode>();
            }

            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });
}
```

And I handle the `onInput` event to capture user input:

```
private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    var searchQuery = args.Value?.ToString()?.Trim();
    searchSubject.OnNext(searchQuery);
}
```

Everything is working fine.

However, I would like to cache results (using `MemoryCache`) so that the call to the endpoint is avoided if the user entered an existing search term. I know how to use memory cache and also distributed cache.

Could this be implemented out-of-the-box in the subscription or do I need to expand the `OnInput` method to skip the call to `OnNext` in an entry exists in the cache?

Comment: i use this in the past [extensions](https://github.com/eXpandFramework/NugetStatistics/blob/master/XpandNugetStats/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs)